# is this the right way to change a class based on time

Tags: php, datetime

I have an if else statement that executed based upon time. If its after this time and before this time echo this. Im just not sure this is correct....

Can anyine help?

```
$opening_from_time = "07:30";
$opening_to_time = "23:30";

$gmt = gmdate('H:i',time());


if ($gmt <= $opening_to_time && >= $opening_from_time){
    echo'<div class="opening_times_times_green">07:30 - 23:00</div>';
   }

else {
      echo '<div class="opening_times_times>07:30 - 23:00</div>';
     }
```

Comment: Does it work?! If yes what do you want to change ?

Comment: It doesnt work.. im wondering if it would be able to calculate based on time with a :   .....

Comment: It must be a typo in your question, but "now" must be in quotes.

Comment: basically i want it to check a set timeframe against the current time.

If the current time fits into that timeframe echo one thing and echo something else if else

Comment: another typo with that "&& >=" ?

Comment: Is the constant `now` actually defined or did you mean `'now'` or simply `time()` instead of `strtotime`?

Comment: time() I have changed that in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing this

```
if ($gmt <= $opening_to_time && >= $opening_from_time){
```

to this

```
if ($gmt <= $opening_to_time && $gmt >= $opening_from_time){
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct, because in 24h format the string is in the same order as your integers of hours and minutes. You could also use strtotime and compare the timestamps.